# Training with GPU very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset of 570,000 images which is split into train, validation and test with a 90%, 5% and 5% split.

I started training the model using transfer learning with MobileNetV2.

Data being loaded in:

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=["0", "10", "5"],
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

Model:

```
baseModel = MobileNetV2(
           include_top=False,
           input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,
           weights='imagenet')

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Model summary:

```
Total params: 2,915,395
Trainable params: 657,411
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

The Nvidia K80 I am using is being utilized:

```
jupyter@tensorflow-4-vm:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Sep  4 16:23:01 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   55C    P0    58W / 149W |  10871MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      8129      C   /opt/conda/bin/python                      10858MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
METRICS = [
      TruePositives(name='tp'),
      FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      Precision(name='precision'),
      Recall(name='recall'),
      AUC(name='auc'),
]

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=METRICS)

CALLBACKS = [
    ReduceLROnPlateau(verbose=1),
    ModelCheckpoint(
        '/home/jupyter/checkpoint/model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5',
        verbose=1),
]
history = model.fit(train_dataset,epochs = 50,verbose=1, batch_size= 32, callbacks= CALLBACKS, validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

But training on a single epoch is extremely slow!
What could possible be the reason for it being this slow?

```
# Batch size = 32

Epoch 1/50
   17/16229 [..............................] - ETA: 196:20:59 - loss: 1.2727 - tp: 169.0000 - fp: 211.0000 - tn: 877.0000 - fn: 375.0000 - accuracy: 0.6409 - precision: 0.4447 - recall: 0.3107 - auc: 0.5755
```

Comment: How are you loading the data, and what batch size are you using?

Comment: Data is being loaded from my Google Cloud Platform Storage Bucket which is mounted on my VM instance. I used a batch size of 32.

Comment: No, I mean how in your code is the data being loaded, this looks like data loading bottleneck.

Comment: Oh i am using image_dataset_from_directory()

Comment: Yes, but how? Please add that code and all model fitting code.

Comment: I have edited the question with all the functions

Comment: What is the image size? What if you increase the batch size to something like 128-256?

Comment: Image size is (224,224,3) which is the required size for MobileNetV2. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think data loading could be the issue. If you loading each file over network, few things to consider. The best way would be to copy data to local storage and then train.
If that is not possible, try using TFRecord for loading data( You can check out here how to use them: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord). Also, ensure storage and VM are in same region.

Comment: I will try copying the data directly to my VM instance instead of mounting the bucket to the instance. If that does not work then I will try TFRecord.

Comment: Also VM instance and storage bucket are in the same region as I am.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by loading the dataset directly to the VM instance using:

```
gcloud compute scp /Users/yudhiesh/Desktop/frames_split.zip jupyter@tensorflow-5-vm:~
```

Then unzipping the folder to the home directory of the VM instance.

Model training is taking less than an hour now per epoch.